# Resuming a surfaceView activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, surfaceview

So i have a game menu with buttons, the start game button changes the contentView with a custome surfaceView, i need to make the game show the menu with the buttons after it is minimized and then resumed (after the view is changed with a surfaceView) so here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cont);
    contButton
            .setVisibility(showContButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

}

public void startGame(View theButton) {
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);
    gameView.resume();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (gameView != null)
        gameView.pause();

    // if (isFinishing())
    // screen.dispose();

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

I can get exactly what i need if i change onResume with :

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (gameView != null) showContButton = true;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cont);
    contButton
            .setVisibility(showContButton ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);


}
```

but i think its a horrible solution can anyone give an idea ?